# Chromebook giving error "ARC crash collector has stopped" after start-up

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook, androidappsonchromeos

I am using a Chromebook Samsung 3 and I keep receiving the error "ARC crash collector has stopped" about 2 minutes after start-up. It appears as a pop-up window that I can close that instantly reappears, not allowing me to navigate around the GUI after those first 2 minutes.

Has anyone else experienced this? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click in the bottom right-hand corner to open the settings menu by selecting the cog icon. Scroll down to the Google Play options and turn this service off. This will delete all Android apps on your device. You can now turn these services back on again and re-load Google Play and your apps.